# show multiple images one by one in a single section with respect to mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show images one by one in a single section with respect to manual mouse scroll.

I try it with mouse click and a time delay.

```
<div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#snowballAppear').click(function () {
                $('#dialo').hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <img id="dialo" style="display: none;margin-left: 100px;margin-top: -150px; position: relative" src="d4.png">
</div>
```

Comment: With SO, you should post your questions with the code you have done so far. Then people can help you. This is not place to get someone to code for you. If you want so, check some freelancing websites to get a programmer for the same.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: k i will show my code

Comment: <div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#snowballAppear').click(function(){
                    $('#dialo').hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(1000);

                    });
                });
            </script>
            <img id="dialo" style="display: none;margin-left: 100px;margin-top: -150px; position: relative"  src="d4.png">
        </div>

Comment: i attached my mouse click code

Comment: @Poojasp Please update your question directly instead of posting as comments. I have updated your question with the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this right there was missing element of ID #snoballapear so i add button maybe you can change later

```js
    var src = ['https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vl8IxeB0ss4/maxresdefault.jpg','http://omg.mn/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bugatai-zurag-1.png'];
   var i = 0;
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).bind('mousewheel',function() {
        $('#dialo').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn();
        if (i==1){
        $('#dialo').attr('src', src[i]);
        i=0;
        }
        else {
        $('#dialo').attr('src', src[i]);
        i=1;
        }
         
      });
    });
```

```css
div{height:500px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
     <img id="dialo" style="display: none;margin-left: 100px;margin-top: -150px; position: relative" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vl8IxeB0ss4/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: i want to replace the mouse click function to mouse scroll function. please help me.

Comment: @Poojasp i edited for your condition whenever you scroll it trigger your img with 3 sec delay

Comment: @Poojasp does this help you

Comment: I think the above code will run without the scroll function.

Comment: @Poojasp no it will not cause it will not trigger by on load only by scroll just try it and you do know wait 3 sec? because your delay timer?

Comment: i want to show multiple images one by one in a single section. The images must show with respect to mouse scroll.

Comment: @Poojasp put your img in array and show in img i will make for random math func if you need depends on how many picture u have. In this example i only add 2 picture thats why i didnt use random integers sake

Comment: @Poojasp does hits help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to show images one by one on click, you can use the same code/function and trigger it on `mousewheel` event as well.

You can use mousewheel plugins for capturing mousewheel event easily like I have done in following example.

`mousewheel` event will give you a variable, that will indicate whether mousewheel was scrolled upwards or downwards and you can move to appropriate slide accordingly:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#next").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showNextSlide();
  });//
  
  $("#prev").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showPrevSlide();
  });//
  
  $("#slider").on("mousewheel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( e.deltaY < 0 ){
      showNextSlide();
    }else{
      showPrevSlide();
    }
  });//#slider mousewheel()
});//document ready()


function showNextSlide(){
  var curActiveIndex = $("#slider img.active").index();
  var numSlides = $("#slider img").length;
  var nextIndex = curActiveIndex >= numSlides - 1 ? 0 : (curActiveIndex + 1);
  $("#slider img.active").removeClass("active");
  $("#slider img").eq( nextIndex ).addClass("active");
}//showNextSlide()

function showPrevSlide(){
  var curActiveIndex = $("#slider img.active").index();
  var numSlides = $("#slider img").length;
  var nextIndex = curActiveIndex <= 0 ? numSlides - 1 : (curActiveIndex - 1);
  $("#slider img.active").removeClass("active");
  $("#slider img").eq( nextIndex ).addClass("active");
}//showPrevSlide()
```

```css
#slider{
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
#slider img{
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
}
#slider img.active{
  opacity: 1;
}


.as-console-wrapper{display: none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <img class="active" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="Slide 1" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food" alt="Slide 1" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature" alt="Slide 1" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion" alt="Slide 1" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats" alt="Slide 1" />
</div><!--#slider-->

<div>
  <button id="prev">previous</button>
  <button id="next">next</button>
</div>
```